# JSF framework without JavaScript

Tags: jsf

Is there any JAva Server Faces framework implementation, that doesn't produce nor uses any JavaScript inside generated output?
No JavaScript nor AJAX, pure HTML with optional static resources like CSS.

If possible, also without using cookies." By framework.

Answer (score 4):

You can just use the standard JSF implementation. The `<h:commandLink>`, `<h:button>` and `<f:ajax>` are the only components which generate and require JavaScript. If you just don't use them, then you're already set. As alternatives you could use `<h:commandButton>` or `<h:link>` respectively and then throw in some CSS to make it look like a link or button respectively.

As to cookies, this is only created when JSF makes (in)directly use of the `HttpSession`. Just toggle to client side state saving by setting `javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD` to `client`, or make JSF stateless by `<f:view transient="true">`. Also and don't use `@SessionScoped` managed beans. `@ViewScoped` is already not possible in stateless JSF — although "useless" is a better term — if you make JSF stateless). Stateless JSF only requires a minimum of Mojarra version 2.1.19, older versions didn't support it. You also need to keep in mind that stateless JSF is more sensitive to forgery attacks, but that's not JSF's fault.

#### See also:

- [When should I use h:outputLink instead of h:commandLink?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4317684/when-should-i-use-houtputlink-instead-of-hcommandlink/4317723#4317723)
- [Difference between h:button and h:commandButton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13070537/difference-between-hbutton-and-hcommandbutton)
- [Why JSF saves the state of UI components on server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5474316/why-does-jsf-need-to-save-the-state-of-ui-components-on-the-server-side/)